# This sign appears in a car park in southern England. What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

The wording seems to tell me it was composed by a non-native speaker. But to my mind it is telling me one of two things:
 Either,(1) not to divide my car into pieces and park the separate parts in different car parks; or (2)  not to park my car somewhere else and arrive on foot at the coffee house.

Does anyone else have any ideas?

**Edit by OP**

Following considerable feedback by people who said they didn't understand what I was asking let me clarify a few points:

I assure you I did not submit this because I had a gripe with the tone - although I do think that it is poor. Nor do I think it reflects an American as opposed to British taste in notices as has been suggested (though I am well aware of the differences). That is not my point. I am complaining about it, and seeking the views of the site as to how it could be said better. As regards taking cars apart - one interpretation of park here only, could be (ridiculously) 'don't park in two or three places simultaneously'. Otherwise it seems odd to be telling people that they cannot park anywhere else. Has anyone else ever seen a sign which says 'Only park here'?

[image: Car Park sign: "All Starbucks Coffee Company Visitors to park in Starbucks car park only."]

Comment: After reading at least twice, you can understand what it means..I think. They probably have problems with visitors parking in nearby other shops car parks.

Comment: @Josh61 well I'm not so daft that I don't get the message, but it could be expressed rather better. If the composer was a non-native speaker we will forgive them. But anyone who has done 13 years of education in an English-speaking country really should do better. Sadly I do not find that is always the case.

Comment: I do agree with you...subject/verb/object.

Comment: It's a bit formal for a sign... Not sure who in their right mind would call it "Starbucks Coffee Company" unless it's actually a corporate office.

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: @Catija Indeed!

Comment: @Josh61 I really put it there as I thought that the many non-native speakers we get on the site might find it an interesting case, of how not to achieve clarity. What should the sign say?

Comment: To visitors;  please park only in Starbucks car park.

Comment: @Josh61 For purists and pedants like us, I'm not sure that does it. Starbucks are not insisting that in order to visit their coffee house visitors be compelled to park in their car park. For all they care their coffee drinkers could park ten miles away and walk. Why don't they come to the point and say *Visitors to Starbucks may park here. Please do not leave your car in the neighbouring Shell petrol station*.

Comment: Yes, an _are_ is missing before _to_. Yes, it's inconsistent to call it "Starbucks Coffee Company" first and then just "Starbucks". Yes, it is pretentious to call Starbucks "Starbucks Coffee Company". Yes, it is annoying to throw so much moot capitalization around. But what bothers me more than anything else is that _all_ visitors are supposed to park. I have **no car**, nor even a license to drive one. _If_ I were to visit this Starbucks I would feel very unwelcome having to procure something to park before being allowed to be a visitor!

Comment: On the other hand, England (at least Southern England) has long been a source of amusing signs for me; I collected pictures of them. "Slow children"  was an endearing warning that the local youth shouldn't be expected to be too bright. And then there was the "It is forbidden to consume alcohol here when so instructed by an authorized and uniformed officer" - or something to that extent. :)

Comment: @oerkelens Yes. I agree with what you say. But I do not like the construction *are to*. On a military base I would expect to see such signs - *All visitors are to report to the Guard Room*. But this is a coffee house trying to attract customers. It would seem more appropriate to begin *Starbucks visitors are welcome to park here - please do not leave your vehicle in the Shell station*.

Comment: I don't understand the point. However obscure the message may be, they are just trying to solve a real or perceived probem. Giving indications to visitors about where they should park their cars is just fine...why not?

Comment: @Josh61 But, Josh, we are an English language site, talking about effective ways of expressing ourselves. We all know what they are trying to say, but they are not saying it well.

Comment: As to the military tone... I agree. I guess I have been numbed down due to my current job. Maybe the author of the sign felt the same way and decided to remove the _are_ for that exact reason. Using "Visitors **are** to park" is too strict, so let's remove that. What goes on in the minds of sign writers...

Comment: @WS2 - and *saying it well*  to you means *Visitors to Starbucks may park here. Please do not leave your car in the neighbouring Shell petrol station*? I think they are clearly having problems with visitors taking up parking spaces from other shops or offices.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, local authorities can apply for permission to stop people drinking alcohol in certain designated areas. These are typically at tourist sites to deter hordes of drunken youth gathering and throwing their beer cans everywhere. The signs will ask them to refrain from drinking alcohol in the area if asked to do so by a Police Officer. Failure to comply could constitute an arrestable offence. I noticed some of these signs outside the Royal Shakespeare Theatre at Stratford-upon-Avon recently.

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, the sign is not telling me, a non-Starbucks customer, that I cannot park in that car park. My interpretation is that it is telling me that if I am a Starbucks visitor I should not park elsewhere. (The Shell station has clearly complained to them about their customers obstructing the Shell site). There is incidentally another sign in the car park which says that only Starbucks visitors should park there - and threatens miscreants with wheel clamping (which has been illegal on private land in the UK for five years).

Comment: And that second sign reads "All that park here to visit Starbucks Coffee Company"?

Comment: @WS2 - what I honestly understand from the sign, however poorly expressed, is that if I am going to their coffe shop, I am requested to park in their car park (not in other spaces). I can't really make any other assumption. If I am on foot, I'd probably not notice  or not care about the sign.

Comment: @oerkelens No. It doesn't say that - though I can understand why you might have thought it did. It is an altogether more professionally produced sign - possibly supplied by their UK Head Office. But they ought to know that they no longer have a right to wheel clamp vehicles irrespective of whether they have permission to park there or not.

Comment: @Josh61 Yes that is what they mean - but poorly said.

Comment: I have *no* idea what any of you are talking about. The sign does not say that all visitors must park. The sign does not say you must or must not dismantle anything. What *on Earth* are y'all talking about? It says a very simple thing in a very straightforward manner. It is not one bit ambiguous. I could not misinterpret it even on purpose. I cannot arrive at any of the alternative meanings listed here, no matter how hard I try. I am at a complete loss.

Comment: I don't understand this- you *don't* want to know what it means, per the title, you state you already know what it means. This seems to be a strawman question posed with the express intention of pointing at some unknown author, possibly a non-native English speaker, to highlight how poor you think they are. Is this really on-topic here?

Comment: @RegDwigнt Well I happen to think it is an extraordinarily inarticulate way to say *If you are coming here, please park in our car park and not on the neighbours' property* - which is what they mean.

Comment: @RegDwigнt To begin with it starts *All Starbucks...customers...*. Some customers may not have cars. And apart from my other criticisms, to me it sounds brusque and dictatorial. Nowhere does it say *please*, or *kindly park in this car park* . It sounds to me a bit like *I'm ordering you to park here*.

Comment: @WS2: nowhere does it say that all customers must have cars. It doesn't even say that *any* customer must have a car. It doesn't even say that any of the customers that are parking must be doing so in cars. It merely says that *if* you're parking, you must be parking in the allocated area. You are free to park a tank, or a plane, a bicycle, or not to park at all. As to brusque or dictatorial, that is completely irrelevant. "I saw a brusque wording, look at it" is not much of an ELU question.

Comment: @RegDwigнt It says *All Starbucks...visitors to park in car park only*. If that does not demonstrate a clear assumption that all visitors have a car, I don't know what would. And it refers to a *car park*. It doesn't say anything about tanks, helicopters etc., so the clearly stated imperious command is that *if you visit us here, you must park your car in the car park (even if you don't have one).* You might well argue that I ought to understand what the sign means. I do. I would also understand someone who said *Toilet quick please piss myself* but it would not be good English.

Comment: Ironically, your question is unclear. 1. Some users believe you need help in understanding the sign. 2. Some do not see any problem in the sign's message 3. Some do not believe the sign was written by a non-native. 4. Not one user has interpreted the sign as saying car owners must park different parts of their cars in different carparks. I am actually interested in how you arrived at first interpretation. I think it is rather curious. If I didn't know you, I might have said you were mistaking *all* for *whole*.

Comment: I had to read the train of comments in order to understand that your real gripe is with the tone of the message/instructions. Starbucks is an American multi national company, it is not John Lewis's, or Fortnum & Mason's whose customers expect formal English, and politeness. Starbuck's customers are a different kettle of fish (I do so like that expression), they are the new generation, the generation of text speak, the generation of "I'm not bothered".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Let me assure you I did not submit this because I had a gripe with the tone - although I do think that it is poor. Nor do I think it reflects an American as opposed to British taste in notices (though I am well aware of that) I am complaining and seeking the views of the site as to how it could be said better. As regards taking cars apart -  one interpretation of *park here only*, could be don't park in two or three places simultaneously.  Otherwise it seems odd to be telling people that they cannot park anywhere else. Have you ever seen a sign which says 'Only park here' before?

Comment: I don't know if you asked this as a joke, man, but it is utterly and completely normal.  Imagine say a "corporate mall" or "strip mall" as Americans would say, or a business park as we say in the UK. Out the front there are (say) ten spaces, each one belonging to a different company (and so labelled).  Or, there are (say) 100 spaces, with 10 groups of 10, each company owns 10 (say) spaces, all of which are labelled.  Obviously, the sign just means Company X business visitors must use that company's spaces.  So what?  By "car park" in final line, they mean either "individual car park space"....

Comment: ... or perhaps "the car-park 'section' so labelled".  So you might have a slight quibble with that.  (Perhaps it would be better written "please use only our spaces.)  Regarding your fundamental question **is this a common sign type** -- it seems really incredible to ask.  Yes, **IT IS UBIQUITOUS**.  I could take 10, maybe 50 such photos when I walk out of this R&D lab today, within a block.

Comment: "not to park my car somewhere else and arrive on foot at the coffee house." its bizare you're not familiar with the ubiquitous- perhaps literally universal - layout of car parking at business parks, where there are (say) 20 spaces and each is labelled in groups or individually by the tenants.  (And there's usually a couple general unlabelled ones.)

Comment: @JoeBlow I do see your point about the business park. But this wasn't a business park. In any event, if I were writing such a sign I would say *Please do not park in bays other than those marked for the company you are visiting*. I can understand anyone telling a driver where they cannot park. It is another thing telling them what they must do - some people could react badly to that. And I see no point in the word *all* at the start. Even you must agree that that should be left out.

Comment: hi WS.  (1) very confusingly your headline and question suggests you simply did not know what the sign means.  {This seems almost unbelievable since, quite simply, that type of sign is ubiquitous.} However subsequently you suggest you certainly understand what it means (ie you have seen this type of sign ubiquitously) but (and fair enough) you don't like the grammar on this particular one...

Comment: then (2) regarding your particular suggestion in italics.  Yeah, I suppose that's OK.  Almost certainly, of the say 10 million such signs in existence, many would be worded exactly like that.  Note that your example is an "all companies" encompassing directive.  (That's fine, there are millions such phrased that way.)  The one in question is only for one company (Ditto.)

Comment: then (3) you mare making much meat of the fact that the sign can be interpreted to mean you conceptually "must" park ("WHAT IF I DONT EVEN HAVE A CAR?! HEH!! HAH HAH!!").  So, it should read more like this: **All SB visitors *who arrived by car and are parking a car*, to park that car in Starbucks car park only.**  OK.  So it's kind of funny that because of the section omitted, there's a mildly ambiguous humour there.  ("Hah ha, but I walked! ).  OK.

Comment: then (4) the phraselet "Starbucks Car Park" is likely poor, inaccurate - it's more likely they mean something like "those slots labelled Starbucks" or "the single slot that is reserved for Starbucks".  Again .. OK.

Comment: now regarding **the issue of the "ALL" up front**.  You're missing something here.  I assume the sign is addressing corporate visitors, not retail customers. For every business, Corporate Visitors are divided neatly in to two brigades .. suppliers (people coming begging to sell you something) and people you asked to come (say, hired solicitors, consultants, engineers, interviewees, etc).  It's totally commonplace in larger settings that you see sings like "travellers must park only to the west" "all suppliers only met from 10am-11am, park in red spaces only" etc. cont...

Comment: .. cont .. here they are emphasising "ALL" visitors to Starbucks.  And again, this "ALL" (suppliers! our own employees! anyone we asked to come here! anyone!) is a very common feature of these very common signs.

Comment: Then...  (5) you've raised the issue of the awkward phrasing "ABC to do XYZ". rather than something like "ABC must XYZ" or "ABC, please do not -XYZ", etc.  It's rather "headlinese" or perhaps "AmE-ish".  OK.  I don't really know what to say about that ... so what?

Comment: Finally possibly (6) .. you point out that it reads as a command.  So, it says essentially "Park here."  Rather than say "Please do not park here".  But so what?  Almost all road signs are "command formatted".  The car has already entered the parking lot: given that, what else would you say?

Comment: And one more point (7). These signs often suffer a **customer / corporate visitor** duality.  Sometimes this is made very clear. ("McDonalds corporate visitors, please use the rear car park only.")  Sometimes even clearer.  ("McDonalds corporate visitors, please use the rear car park only. Customers, please enjoy any parking you wish!")  Sometimes it is terse ("Corporate visitors park at rear.") or even terser ("Visitor parking space") -- it's understood that "visitor" is different from "Customer".  cont ..

Comment: ..cont.. If you're not familiar with that common distinction ("Visitor" implying corporate visitor, quite distinct from "Customer"), then, that's just you.  I'm not familiar with 99.9% of things in the universe.  But it is **completely commonplace**.  It's so commonplace that it is **probably one of the reasons this QA is so confusing**.  Everyone else "in the world" as it were, other than you, knows "Visitor" implies "company-related visitor" (not retail customer), it's so obvious nobody has even mentioned it here.

Comment: That being said, note that it's completely possible that, the 19 year old minimum-wage employee who affixed this sign, **did not have a fucking clue** about "corporate visitors" versus "retail clients" and so on.  It's just a completely ubiquitous, totally uninteresting, piece of mental furniture that you see in every car park ever built, so said minimum-wage employee would have just pasted it up with no real understanding or concern either way.  (BTW, you have not told us whether, in fact, from context the sign appears to imply which group .. thus ...

Comment: .. in fact is it the type of Starbucks where you (I mean a retail customer), CAN IN FACT PARK?  is it a drive-in Starbucks?  or is this "round the back" (or indeed is this at a Starbucks corporate office, not a retail location) or something and the parking lot is clearly only for corporate visitor use?  (And, apparently, shared with other customers.)

Comment: I must say that it is difficult to believe other than that my **extensive comments here, would completely clear up this situation.**

Answer (score 7):

There's no way this was composed by a non-native English speaker; it displays impressive mastery of no fewer than three aspects of formal English:

- Headlinese: zero copula, omitted article: "All [...] Visitors [*are requested*] to park in [*the*] Starbucks car park only." Note also that "[*are*] to" is a short form relative to the alternatives "*should"*, or indeed "*please*".
- Corporate English: the use of the full company name "Starbucks Coffee Company" could only be improved by also writing it in full at the second occurrence; also note the use of the term "Visitors" (capitalised) as internal jargon for "customers".
- Bureaucratic English: the flat, impersonal tone would be very difficult for a non-native English speaker to achieve. Note the use of the passive indicative in place of the imperative mood, as well as the care taken to avoid any suggestion of where customers may have been parking instead of the correct car park - after all, to do so could be taken as an admission of liability for their conduct.

In practical terms, it's rarely a good idea to let on what some people may have been doing wrong, as it actively encourages others to do the same by providing (a) the inspiration to do so and (b) social proof: someone arriving at the Starbucks and confronted with a full car park and a sign asking them not to park in the adjacent property may well think "Well, if *other* people are parking there..."

Finally, consider that the primary target of the sign as communication may well not be the customers reading it. If the composition of the sign was indeed occasioned by a complaint from the occupant of an adjacent property then the *primary* target is the corporate higher-up who transmitted the complaint while the *secondary* target is the complainant, with actual customers coming a distant third.

Comment: Good - and also satirical - answer.

Comment: Fourth bullet point: Apostrophes only cause friction.

Comment: But what is the function of the word *only*? What did the sign's author intend it to mean?

Comment: @WS2: If the sign just told customers that they *have* to park in the Starbucks car park, customers might theoretically feel they are not welcome without a car to park. With the word *only* the real intent is a bit more explicit: The collective of all Starbucks customers is not supposed to spill over to adjacent car parks; collectively they are to park only in the Starbucks car park. This permits non-parking customers. This global view also indicates that a small fraction of infractions for good reason such as dual customership is probably not a big issue.

Comment: I don't see why any of those bullet points would exclude non-native speakers from being the sign composers. It's perfectly possible for a non-native speaker to master jargon and Headlinese. (Incidentally, there are no passives on the sign; a passive would have been “all visitors to be parked in Starbucks car park only”, which would have made for even more alternative readings, but would probably not be appreciated much by the actual clientele.)

Answer (score 0):

We can form the imperative in different ways:

**All employees *must park* in the spaces marked.

All employees *are to park* in the spaces marked.**

The sign is patterned after the second form, but with the word "are" removed because of space considerations. Signs are similar to headlines in that words are dropped because there's little room.

Comment: I think they refer to *visitors*.

Comment: Just an example. I'm talking about the imperative.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for (2), with the addition that 'somewhere else' means 'the car park of a neighbouring company' (or 'the street').

And I'd put 'are' between 'Visitors' and 'to'.

Comment: That would seem a rather imperious command. *You are to park here!* My comment above supplies my own suggestion.